# How can I trigger some code to run in the view from the view model?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

What is the best way for the view model to "ask" the view to do something, (e.g. manipulate on of the controls)? I don't think that the view model sending events violates MVVM as after all the INotifyPropertyChanged interface is an example of view models sending events to views.

I realize that having code behind in the view is not considered ideal from a MVVM perspective, so I could use an attached behavior to manipulate a particular control for example but the problem remains - how do I ask the attached behavior to do something from my view model?

I could have Boolean dependency property on my view with property changed event handler which runs the code I need to run. I could then bind this property to a property on my view model and then toggle the value of this property whenever I want to trigger the code to run. However this seems like a hack.

I could have an event on the view model and then explicitly attach this event to an event handler in the view in code but this seems anti MVVM - I should be able to achieve the connection using binding.

This must be a fairly common scenario, are there any standard solutions?

Comment: What code in the view? View should only display things. No code there. If you want to do something conditionally or convert something then use bindings and converters.

Comment: You have to give an example here. If you want to manipulate UserControls then you should bind to their DependencyProperties. If they are your own controls then you can write your own DependencyProperties.

Comment: @FCin 7 - I need to manipulate one of the controls in the view in a way which I can't achieve with binding. I can get around the need for code behind with attached behavior - have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: You should see MVVM as 3 layers, Model does not know anything about ViewModel or View, ViewModel know Model, but does not know View. View only knows ViewModel, you should be able to replace or remove any layer, and the rest should still work. There is nothing against have code behind in View as long as you program does not fall apart if you replace the View layer with something else.

Comment: I could have an event on the view model and then explicitly attach this event to an event handler in the view in code --> This dose not anti MVVM. View listen to ViewModel's PropertyChanged event for binding to work, so it's ok for View to listen to your custom event on ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use an event aggregator or a messenger to send an event or message from the view model that the view handles in a loosely coupled way. Both the view and the view model know only about the event aggregator but they don't know anything about each other. Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) for more information about the concept.

Another common approach is to implement an interface in the view and inject the view model with this interface, e.g.:

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public partial class Window1 : Window, IDoSomething
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel(this);
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //do something...
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(IDoSomething doSomething)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

This doesn't break the MVVM pattern as the view model knows about and is dependant only on an interface.

Comment: One thing I need to do is to force validation on the controls when the OK button is pressed on the view - I understand that I can do that with control.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource(). I know its best not to have code behind in the view but can't see another way to do it. Do you think this use case is good candidate for the techniques you have presented?

Comment: I am using view model first so my view is a UserControl and hosted inside a ContentControl placed in a window. The hooking up of the view model to view is done implicitly via a data template. Is there a way I can apply something like the second approach in this case?

Comment: The answer to your first question is no. Your should implement the validation logic in the view model class by implementing the [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx) interface.